# How to hide (not close just hide) a form automatically after 5 seconds in C#?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form which is need to hide automatically, form load's after 5 seconds.

**Note:** This form's controlbox must be disabled & has no any button.

How could I do that exactly?

Comment: I can't set tick..Please post with source code...Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the whole code snippet, just copy and paste it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        t1.Tick += t1_Tick;
        t1.Interval = 5000; //5000 ms = 5 seconds
        t1.Start();
    }

    void t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        t1.Stop(); //it should be stopped after hiding the form
    }
```

Comment: I know it.. But I want to hide it with timer... Please post source code.. Thanks dude!!

Comment: Will `Hide();` be called *ad infinitum* with five seconds' interval?

Comment: Its working.. Super Dude..!! You are the man!!!!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks to mention. I've corrected